# Pass a different declared type to a binding procedure Fortran

Tags: class, fortran, intel-fortran

Given the following code

```
  type t1 
     integer :: dum 
  type(aop), alloctable  :: bc(:) 
  end type t1 

 type aop 
   procedure(A_INT), pass(t1), pointer :: ptr => null()
 end type aop 

 abstract interface 
    subroutine A_INT ( this ) 
            import t1
            class(t1) , intent(in) :: this 
    end subroutine 

 end interface
```

Can someone explain why this is illegal? At least the compiler says

```
error #8170: The passed-object dummy argument is missing from the procedure interface.   [A_INT]
            procedure(A_INT), pass(t1),
   -------------------^
```

**UPDATED**

When I do this instead

```
  type t1 
     integer :: dum 
  type(aop), alloctable  :: bc(:) 
  end type t1 

 type aop 
   procedure(A_INT), pass(this), pointer :: ptr => null()
 end type aop 

 abstract interface 
    subroutine A_INT ( this ) 
            import t1
            class(t1) , intent(in) :: this 
    end subroutine 

 end interface
```

I get following error

```
error #8262: For a type-bound procedure that has the PASS binding attribute, the first dummy argument must have the same declared type as the type being defined.   [THIS]
             subroutine A_INT(  this
```

which I guess this means that the compiler expects the first argument to be of `aop` type? Is it not possible to have `this` being of `t1` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pass(t1)` bu there is no dummy argument `t1`, there is only the argument `this` which is of type `t1`.

With a single dummy argument I would typically not use any explicit `pass` here at all. A passed dummy argument makes sense only when it is of the same type as the type in which the pointer is defined. Otherwise, for arguments of other types, **just use `nopass`.**

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir that makes sense.  So saying `pass(this)` would make the compiler think that `this` is of type `aop` how do I change it so that it is of type `t1`.
PS: I actually have many more dummy arguments that is why I wanted to have an explicit pass to reduce it.

Comment: Oh, I see now, your design looks really strange. If you have no passed dummy argument, you need `nopass`. But are you sure you donjt actually need `this` to be of type `aop` and the access the `ptr` argument inside?

Comment: So what I need is to do this `call t1_% bc(1)% ptr( ..... ) ` where `t1_` is of TYPE `t1`. I want by this call to pass `t1_` automatically without having it part of the arguments in the call

Comment: I see, as I said, just remove the pass altogether. You do not need it.

Comment: By you answer I understand that what I am trying is not possible. In that case, then, yes I don't need it to be a type bound procedure to `t1`

Comment: The reason why I have a separate `type aop` is because the pointer "ptr" is an array of pointers which is not directly possible in Fortran as I understand it.

Comment: Just use nopass.

Comment: You can't have the `t1_` passed automatically. It is not possible.

Comment: Great,. Thanks for confirming this!